# Why doesn't the text inside my text field disappear on click?

Tags: javascript, html

In the following example

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

There is a text field with text "Type something..." which disappears upon click

I have included my nearly identical code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">    
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <title></title>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <meta name="description" content="">    
    <meta name="author" content="">    
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>    
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">    
</head>    
<body>    
<input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Type something…"> <span class="help-inline">Associated help text!</span>the
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Can somebody tell me why my text does not disappear upon clicking?

Comment: Does work on my browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox): the placeholder text disappears as soon as I click or otherwise focus the text field. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Chrome and the text does not disappear upon clicking. It disappears after writing into it. When you delete the input, the placeholder appears again.